# Identifying feature OID from Geometry object using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, geometry

I know ArcPy allows you to access geometries directly using the [CopyFeatures_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000035000000) method. Note in their code sample for the Geometry object, it is very simple to copy the geometries to in-memory objects of type [Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Geometry/000v00000095000000/) (and extremely fast). The geometry object of course relates to the geometry/shape and completely bypasses attribute information.

My question is whether there is a way to identify the OID of each geometry cheaply?

A little background in what I am trying to perform:

1. For all feature classes in a geodatabase
2. Read through each feature's geometry
3. Go over the points in the geometry
4. Calculate the distances between the points
5. If the distance is below a threshold, that specific feature needs to marked for review (meaning I need either the OID/FID or any other field to identify it).

As I am still in ArcGIS 10.0, I would prefer to not use cursors that seem to work a lot slower than simply dealing with the geometries.

Comment: Can you tell us why you are doing this? Presumably you are looking to remove excess vertices or simplify polygons.

Comment: Also when you say "If the distance is below a threshold", is "the distance" ANY of the distances between any consecutive pair of vertices, a sum of all of the distances (perimeter) or some other measurement?

Comment: How are you currently looping over each feature in a feature class other than with a cursor?

Comment: Presuming you ARE currently using a cursor, have you tried specifying just the SHAPE and OBJECTID fields for the cursor's fields argument?

Comment: @blah238 Let me try and answer all your questions. 1) I am trying to remove excess vertices. Visually, I noticed ~300 vertices following a (visually straight) road of ~100 feet length (this seems excessive). 2) The distance below a threshold is the distance between two consecutive vertices (pnt1 to pnt2, pnt2 to pnt3, etc). 3) Right now I am looping only through the geometries by using a geometry list (see the example in the Geometry link above). 4) I am not using a cursor, as even a cursor with simply SHAPE and OID attributes is extremely slow compared with the geometry method alone.

Comment: in postgis you could use st_simplify : http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Simplify.html is there similiat function in ArgGis ?

Comment: @simplexio     I am not trying to simplify though. I am trying to identify if there is a need to worry about excessive vertices.

Answer (score 3):

You can't determine the OID directly from the geometry object, it doesn't know anything about it. The row object in a cursor has that field, just use `row.OID` in your cursor.

You probably want to just [Generate a Near Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001n000000) and then [Select by Attributes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000071000000) on the new table against the distance field to find geometries that are too close (`[]NEAR_DIST] < X`). Once you've run select by attributes you can use a cursor to iterate over only the OIDs that matter:

```
oids = set()
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(r'in_memory\new_near_table'):
    oids.add(row.IN_FID)
    oids.add(row.NEAR_FID)
```

And from there you can select by attributes on the original table:

```
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("original_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", 'OID in (%s)' % (', '.join(str(oid) for oid in sorted(oids))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am trying to avoid using cursors to solve this problem as they are extremely slow in 10. A Near Table would work if the FCs where points, these are all polygons though. Perhaps a polygon to point, and then Near would do the trick though. Thanks!

Comment: The near tools work on every geometry type, not just points.

Comment: They do work on every geometry type, but if I run a Near Tool on a polygon it will not report back the distances between each vertex in the polygon.